# how to get dynamic timezone of system

Tags: .net, timezone

How can i get my machine timezoneinfo dynamically? right now i am doing it by hard code timezone.

```
        string indTimeZoneKey = "**India Standard Time**";
        TimeZoneInfo indTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(indTimeZoneKey);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Local` property of  [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx).